# Android drag two images on canvas

Tags: android, imageview, android-canvas

My end goal here is to be able to add two (or more) images to a view/canvas, then turn that canvas into a single bitmap.  I've seen many similar SO posts about dragging images around on a view, however, none of them cover dragging multiple images.

I am currently using the matrix commands to rotate and zoom, which work fine but only for one image.  The code I am using is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894736/rotate-zoom-drag-image-in-android-imageview) post.  The issue here is that using fill_parent on the image will only allow for one image to be dragged because it is on top of the other image.  Using wrap_content will only allow the image to be dragged within the confines of how big the image currently is, producing a cropped looking image.

So, is there anyway to edit this code (or use fresh code) to allow multiple images to be dragged and/or zoomed?  As I've mentioned, there are many other SO posts about this but none have any solid answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the demo app from the project [Android Multitouch Controller](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/), pretty much everything is done for you already. It lets you drag, rotate, and scale many images on a custom View.  I've used this in the past for a custom image cropper, and it worked out great.

As for turning the resulting Canvas into a Bitmap, I've got a modified version of the Android Multitouch Controller project to do exactly that.  You can see [that project on GitHub](https://github.com/wsanville/modified-multitouch-controller).

Comment: Thanks, I've noticed this library as well but was looking for more of a custom solution since I'll need to do a lot of tweaking.  I'll give this library a shot and see if it will meet my needs.

Comment: I'd use it again, I found it pretty easy to adapt for my purposes, and it works reasonably well.